# Paytm initiateTransaction API is failing with resultCode="2006" and resultMsg="Mid is invalid"

Tags: java, payment-gateway, paytm

I am trying to call initiateTransaction Paytm gateway API `/theia/api/v1/initiateTransaction?mid=%s&orderId=%s`, I am following documentation here: `https://business.paytm.com/docs/api/initiate-transaction-api?ref=payments` with all correct as per documentation but I am getting error "Mid is invalid", but in actual it's correct. I am using `mid` and `apiKey` of test environment. Please hep me on where am I making the mistake.

My Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.paytm.pg.merchant.PaytmChecksum;

@Service
public class PaytmGatwayService {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String baseUrl = "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in";
        String mid = "<TEST_ENV_MID>";
        String orderId = "abc1234567";
        String apiKey = "<TEST_ENV_API_KEY>";

        JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
        body.put("requestType", "Payment");
        body.put("mid", mid);
        body.put("orderId", orderId);
        body.put("callbackUrl", "https://localhost:4200/");
        body.put("websiteName", "WEBSTAGING");

        JSONObject txnBody = new JSONObject();
        txnBody.put("value", String.valueOf("3520.0"));
        txnBody.put("currency", "INR");
        body.put("txnAmount", txnBody);

        JSONObject userInfo = new JSONObject();
        userInfo.put("custId", "custmer123456");
        userInfo.put("email", "user@email.com");
        body.put("userInfo", userInfo);

        JSONObject head = new JSONObject();
        head.put("channelId", "WEB");
        String checksum = PaytmChecksum.generateSignature(body.toString(), apiKey);
        head.put("signature", checksum);

        JSONObject paytmParams = new JSONObject();
        paytmParams.put("body", body);
        paytmParams.put("head", head);
        String post_data = paytmParams.toString();

        String postUrl = String.format("/theia/api/v1/initiateTransaction?mid=%s&orderId=%s", mid, orderId);

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(baseUrl + postUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {

        }
        String responseData = "";
        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            DataOutputStream requestWriter = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            requestWriter.writeBytes(post_data);
            requestWriter.close();

            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader responseReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            if ((responseData = responseReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.append("Response: " + responseData);
            }
            responseReader.close();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Version of paytm-checksum dependency is `1.2.1`
System.out.append output:

```
Response: {"head":{"requestId":null,"responseTimestamp":"1684729867186","version":"v1"},"body":{"extraParamsMap":null,"resultInfo":{"resultStatus":"F","resultCode":"2006","resultMsg":"Mid is invalid"}}}
```

Comment: This was eventually a config issue from Paytm side.

Comment: How you solved this issue then? @Shashi-ranjan

Comment: Contact customer care, they will enable you for the first time.

Comment: Okey Thanks, I have contacted them.